# Swipe to open push notification shows empty nothingness and also makes me sad

Tags: bug, ios-app

Using an iPhone 6, iOS 8.1, I have a reproducible issue with push notifications:

1. A really cool push notification comes to my phone over the data-waves with a subject like "Hey bro, I answered your question with a picture of my cat Rommel!"
2. Me, being the touch-savvy user that I am, swipe the notification to instantly take me to the StackExchange iOS app.
3. The StackExchange iOS app loads up and shows me the awesome blue nav bar, and ... WHITE. Yep! Whiteness. Now, don't get me wrong, I really love white (I have white shirts and a white mouse and I wish my teeth were white). But in this one particular case, I think I should actually be seeing some text and a picture of Rommel the cat.

y/n?

P.S. This is probably a duplicate, but mine is better because it is about cats also.

Edit: Super sad that it's a duplicate, but I did the right thing and flagged it as a duplicate. But given how much effort (and cats) went into writing this, I'm leaving it.